# Does Altura Flash Transmitter(Trigger) can be locked for continuous shooting in wired shutter release mode?

Tags: triggers

I recently bought the cheap Altura Flash Kit([product link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HK0A6LQ)) for my Canon 750D. I am successfully using the Flash Transmitter as a wired shutter release but could not figure out how to use it in continuous shooting. I want to use this as a continuous trigger for long exposure photography (Star Trails, trailing lights etc.).

Can anyone please help me on this? If this is not possible, please suggest a cheap alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the instructions to see if it mentions bulb mode. If there is no  bulb mode for the remote, put the camera in bulb mode and use the wired shutter release. You will need to hold down the button for the length of the exposure.

If you don't want to hold the button down continuously, there are other cheap wired remotes that will lock in the open position.   [$7.50 Vello wired remote](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/765659-REG/Vello_RS_C1II_RS_C1II_Wired_Remote_Switch.html)

You can also buy another cheap wireless remote that includes Bulb mode. [$39.95 Vello Remote](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/749989-REG/Vello_RW_C1_FreeWave_Wireless_Remote_Shutter.html)

Any cheap Infrared remote like the Canon RC-6 will also allow you to do wireless bulb exposures. In bulb mode the first click opens the shutter and the second click closes the shutter.  [$19.89 Canon RC-6](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/683524-REG/Canon_4524B001_RC_6_Wireless_Remote_Control.html)